# I'm creating a sign up form for an image upload but when I put the information in it says you have an error am I missing some code?

Tags: html, forms, image-upload

I created a signup form for an upload image, but when I enter information
in there it says you have an error, but I examined everything and I don't see a coding error. Could it be that I'm missing a good chunk of code? or I hace a coding error I'm missing a semicolon or parentheses because I don't see anything.

```
<?php 

include_once "dbh.php";

$first = $_POST['first'];

$last = $_POST['last'];

$uid = $_POST['uid'];

$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (first, last, username, password)

VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$uid', '$pwd')";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$uid' AND first='$first'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);       

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $userid = $row['id'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO profileimg (userid, status)

    VALUES ('$userid', 1)";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    header("Location: index.php");
}

 } else {
  echo "You have an error!";
 }

 ?>
```

Here's The html:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
          if ($_SESSION['id'] == 1) {
              echo "You are logged in as user #1";
          }
          echo "<form action='upload.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <input type='file' name='file'>
        <button type='submit' name='submit'>UPLOAD</button>
        </form>";
 } else {
     echo "You are not logged in!";
     echo "<form action='signup.php' method='POST'>
     <input type='text' name='first' placeholder='First name'>
     <input type='text' name='last' placeholder='Last name'>
     <input type='text' name='uid' placeholder='Username'>
     <input type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Password'>
     <button type='submit' name='submitSignup'>Signup</button>
     </form>";
 }
   ?>
     <p>Login as user!</p>
       <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" name="submitLogin">Login</button>
       </form>

     <p>Logout as user!</p>
     <form action="logout.php" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" name="submitLogout">Logout</button>
     </form>
```

[Screenshot of table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6u4bT.png)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help i'm getting ready to check right now!

Comment: Yes my user table matches username $uid

Comment: So I added the semicolon but it didn't work so i'm going to check Rk003 solution

Comment: I think you should add html form document.

Comment: Okay I'll do that

Comment: Ok i got the html

Comment: Yupp! code Seems correct buddy. Why your query is failed  I think solution of the problem is data in SQL table

Comment: Ok thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a semicolon at line

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (first, last, username, password)
```

and also you have put a **`** in line

```
 echo "You have an error!";
 }`
```

I have fixed those syntax errors and if you still get some error please provide the html code from which you are taking input and make sure database connection is made properly.

Edited code::

```
<?php 

include_once "dbh.php";

$first = $_POST['first'];

$last = $_POST['last'];

$uid = $_POST['uid'];

$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (first, last, username, password);

VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$uid', '$pwd')";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$uid' AND first='$first'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);       

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $userid = $row['id'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO profileimg (userid, status)

    VALUES ('$userid', 1)";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    header("Location: index.php");
}

 } else {
  echo "You have an error!";
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: what do you mean by that give you a screenshot

Comment: @NajmaMuhammad yes buddy and also add screenshot of mysql table.

Comment: when you signup for the upload image and if you miss an input field or something it will echo out an message that says "You got an error" so i dont have an actual error so the screenshot for that will be no use, but i can give you a screenshot of my user table that is phpmyadmin would that be okay

Comment: Actually I want the table structure because here your query is unsuccessful. And there must be something related with database causing it.

Comment: do you know how to put a screenshot on here

Comment: you can add it in question, just edit the question and you can include your image

Comment: Click on image button and browse or paste it

Comment: is data being inserted to your table??

Comment: No it's not going in